# What is the problem with the pandas to csv in my code?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, export-to-excel

I am running this code for a project I am doing for fun to find patterns in Disneyland wait times:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df_pirates_all = pd.read_csv(
    "https://cdn.touringplans.com/datasets/pirates_of_caribbean_dlr.csv",usecols=['date','datetime','SPOSTMIN'],
    parse_dates=['date', 'datetime'], 
)
df_pirates_all['ride'] = 'pirates'
df_pirates_all['open'] = ~((df_pirates_all['SPOSTMIN'] == -999))

df_pirates = df_pirates_all.set_index('datetime').sort_index()
df_pirates = df_pirates.loc['2017-01-01 06:00':'2017-02-01 00:00']
df_pirates = df_pirates.resample('15Min').ffill()


df_star_tours_all = pd.read_csv(
    "https://cdn.touringplans.com/datasets/star_tours_dlr.csv", usecols=['date','datetime','SPOSTMIN'],
    parse_dates=['date', 'datetime']
)
df_star_tours_all['ride'] = 'star_tours'
df_star_tours_all['open'] = ~((df_star_tours_all['SPOSTMIN'] == -999))

df_star_tours = df_star_tours_all.set_index('datetime').sort_index()
df_star_tours = df_star_tours.loc['2017-01-01 06:00':'2017-02-01 00:00']
df_star_tours = df_star_tours.resample('15Min').ffill()

df_space_all = pd.read_csv(
    "https://cdn.touringplans.com/datasets/space_mountain_dlr.csv", usecols=['date','datetime','SPOSTMIN'], 
    parse_dates=['date', 'datetime']
)
df_space_all['ride'] = 'space'
df_space_all['open'] = ~((df_space_all['SPOSTMIN'] == -999))

df_space = df_space_all.set_index('datetime').sort_index()
df_space = df_space.loc['2017-01-01 06:00':'2017-02-01 00:00']
df_space = df_space.resample('15Min').ffill()


all_data = pd.concat([df_pirates, df_star_tours, df_space]).reset_index()
all_data = (
    all_data
        # Drop any "NaN" values in the column 'ride'
        .dropna(subset=['ride', ])
        # Make datetime and ride a "Multi-Index"
        .set_index(['datetime', 'ride'])
        # Choose the column 'SPOSTMIN'
        ['SPOSTMIN']
        # Take the last index ('ride') and rotate to become column names
        .unstack()
)
# print (all_data)

for month, group in all_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(f'{month}.xlsx') as writer:
        for day, dfsub in group.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')):
            dfsub.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='day')
```

However I am running into this error

```
FileCreateError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '2017-01-31 00:00:00.xlsx'
```

and it is connected to the dfsub.to_excel line.

It mostly got fixed by the comments, however, only one sheet is appearing and it only has the last day of data (1-31-17) instead of individual sheets for 1-1-17,1-2-17,etc.

Comment: Some of the characters in that file name aren't valid, as it explains

Comment: I just looked at the results and the month is giving me the 2017-01-31 00:00:00 when I want to have it say January 2017.xlsx . Any ideas on how to get it.

Comment: If the question is just how to get a string like that from a `datetime` object, we don't need to see all that pandas stuff.

Comment: Try using `pd.ExcelWriter(f'{month.strftime("%B %Y")}.xlsx')`

Comment: @cs95 that does most of it but how do I get the individual day into sheets and any explanation as to why the Nemo ffill wouldn't work but the others work.

Comment: You're asking me two separate questions at the same time that have nothing to do with each other. Please edit your question to focus on one question at a time. Like @KarlKnechtel said, we are here to answer specific questions (i.e., "how to convert date into formatted string", not "tell me everything that's wrong with my code".)

Comment: Alright. I edited it to have it mainly deal with the csv although now just putting it into the individualized days within the month.

Comment: The symbol ":" is not allowed in Windows file names. Change your file name to something that does not contain ":".

Comment: If only one sheet appears, you should change `dfsub.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='day')` with `dfsub.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=day)` (replace the constant value `'day'` with the content of the `day` variable)

Comment: @Serge Ballesta doing the day without quotes would give me this: “Type error: object of type time stamp has no len()”

Comment: I did not check the type of `day`. If it is a pandas Timestamp, you have just to convert it to string with `str(dat)`, or probably better `str(day.date())`, or with a custom format `day.strftime(format)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What got it fixed was changing the code from

```
for month, group in all_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(f'{month}.xlsx') as writer:
        for day, dfsub in group.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')):
            dfsub.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='day')
```

to

```
for month, group in all_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(f'{month.strftime("%B %Y")}.xlsx') as writer:
        for day, dfsub in group.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')):
            dfsub.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=str(day.date()))
```

with the suggestions that were made.

Answer (score 1):

For the first error based on the code you don’t care about the specific date + time so do this:

`with pd.ExcelWriter(f'{month.date()}.xlsx'):`

This will convert the datetime object to a date object

Your second error is saying you are attempting to make a column that isn’t all unique an index which pandas won’t allow.

Maybe there are field you can combine or use another one?

Comment: Tried and it now shows only the last day of data when the goal is to have the individual day be in a separate sheet i.e. the excel reading 2017-01 and the sheets saying 2017-01-01, 2017-01-02, etc.