# Save scraping results one by one into Excel or CSV file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have a crawler code as follows:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from datetime import datetime

def crawl(id):
    try:
        url = 'https://www.china0001.com.cn/project/{0:06d}.html'.format(id)
        print(url)
        content = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
        tbody = soup.find("table", attrs={"id":"mse_new"}).find("tbody", attrs={"class":"jg"})
        tr = tbody.find_all("tr")
        rows = []
        for i in tr[1:]:
            rows.append([j.text.strip() for j in i.findAll("td")])
        out = dict([map(str.strip, y.split('：')) for x in rows for y in x])
        return out

    except AttributeError:
        return False

data = list()
for id in range(699998, 700010):
    print(id)
    res = crawl(id)
    if res:
        data.append(res)

if len(data) > 0:
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index = False)
```

In this code, the result dataframe `df` will be writen to an Excel file after the whole scraping process is finished.

Now I want to save the scraping results one by one into Excel or CSV file during the scraping process, how could I modify the code above?

Thanks.

**Updates:**

```
MAX_WORKERS = 30
ids = range(700000, 700050)
workers = min(MAX_WORKERS, len(ids))

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(workers) as executor:
    res = executor.map(crawl, sorted(ids))

data = list(res)

if len(data) > 0:
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv('test.csv', mode = 'a', header = True, index = False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using `to_csv` with `header=False, index=False`

**Ex:**

```
for id in range(699998, 700010):
    res = crawl(id)
    if res:
        df = pd.DataFrame([res])
        df.to_csv('test.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: Sorry, I get an error: `TypeError: to_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'`

Comment: Oh sorry that option is only available in `.csv` for excel you need to use `startrow`

Comment: So, I need to use `df.to_csv('test.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)`, right?

Comment: I try to apply your code to multiprocess scraping, but it raises an error `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'keys'`, could you please have a look to updates of my question? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I’d recommend looking at my question on here:
[What is the problem with the pandas to csv in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807176/what-is-the-problem-with-the-pandas-to-csv-in-my-code/62807230#62807230).
I’d recommend looking at the answers for the daily sheets then apply and modify it to fit your program